# Read post data in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, post

I am new to web development maybe the problem I am trying to solve is a very basic one but I have googled a lot for a solution couldn't find one.
I have two web pages `one` and `two`

The below is `one.html`

```
<form id="requestForm" #requestForm ngNoForm action="{{requestUrl}}" method="POST">
<div *ngIf="requestmodel">
    <button class="btn-flat waves-effect waves-light transparent regNrmS2BN" type="submit" id="submitForm" style="color: transparent; background-color: transparent;">Pay</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" [ngModel]="requestmodel.name" />
</div>
</form>
```

This above form gets automatically posted to the next web page `two.html` and below is the code for that which is written in `ComponentOne`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.requestmodel = this.requestService.getRequest();
    this.requestUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/two';
    this.submitMe();
}

submitMe() {
    let me = this;
    if ($('#submitForm') && $('#submitForm')[0])
        $('#submitForm')[0].click();
    else
        setTimeout(function () { me.submitMe(); }, 100);
}
```

The problem is how do I read the form data in `ComponentTwo` and the requirement is I should not use `Service` for this else there wouldn't be any problem at all.
So how can I accomplish this without a service class?

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to use EventEmitter and @Output to access to this event outside. Then use it in another html file as event and pass variables to your typescript file as $event.

I hope I got your question right and didn't mislead you